# When aren't products iterated coproducts?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Multiplication of natural numbers can be understood as iterated addition, and we can understand binary Cartesian products as set-indexed coproducts; for sets $X$ and $Y$,

$$X\times Y\cong\coprod_XY\cong\coprod_YX.$$

The internalization of indexed coproducts is dependent sums, so we need these to ask the question

> What categories with dependent sums does this relationship fail in for objects $X$ and $Y$? Is there a name for categories where this property holds?

Comment: In enriched category theory, this kind of phaenomena is linked to be tensored (or copowered). See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/powered+and+copowered+category.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti That's interesting, but I'm not familiar enough with enriched category theory to suss out the connection; could you elaborate on it a bit more?

Comment: Why doesn't the section "relation to the product" at
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dependent+sum
answer your question?

Comment: @AchimKrause That definitely does answer it, I'm embarrassed. If you'd like to post that as an answer I'll accept it, or if you don't want to I can delete the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A discussion of the relation between dependent coproducts and cartesian products is found at

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dependent+sum